# Trouble with Errors on Unix sh with if statements

Tags: if-statement, unix, sh

I am having a problem with the code below with if statements. It has three different arguments, I'm not sure if one or all of them are wrong.

```
#!/bin/sh


1=C
2=S
(1/2)=C  <---- This might be a problem

if [ $1 == "C*" ]
then
    echo "The city is:"

else [ $2 ==  "S*" ]
then
    echo "The state is:"

else [ $1 -a $2 == "B*" ]
then
    echo "The city and state is:"

else [ $1 -o $2 -ne "C*" "S*" "B*" ]
then
    echo "Not found!"
fi
    echo End of script
```

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, but it might be worth spending a day with a BASH tutorial.  It'll be worth your time if you are going to spend any time at all reading or writing BASH (or any Bourne Shell derivative).  The BASH manual is where to go after the tutorial;  I wouldn't start with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numbers as variables is very unwise idea. Numbers are used to represent command line parameters.

Also this construction is AFAIK unknown to bash: `(1/2)=C`

Also this construction:

```
else [ $2 ==  "S*" ]
then
```

is wrong, should be some something like:

```
elif [ $2 ==  "S*" ]
then
```

Also this:

```
else [ $1 -o $2 -ne "C*" "S*" "B*" ]
```

is odd, you use `-ne` which is for compare numbers, for strings use `!=`

And also a lot of other errors/problems challenging constructions I have no time to mention.